# Handle ForceTouch in WatchKit

Tags: watchkit, force-touch

My WKInterfaceController isnt static. On every call, there will be a new Game loaded.

If i ForceTouch on this Cotroller there comes my Menu with NewGame, restart and so on.

How can i avoid a reload of my WKInterfaceController, when the User DONT click on a menuitem button?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code in `awakeWithContext()` instead of `willActivate()`

as when you forceTouch ,your  WKInterfaceController will reload and reEnter willActivate()